# Identifying Instruments within a music file

Tags: frequency-spectrum, python, music, classification

Say I have a file that contains a few musical instruments, how can Identify the name of each one (ultimate goal) or at least the category they belong to, like wind instruments?
For example, if I load a music file that contains guitar, piano, and bass, I want the output to be "Guitar, piano, bass", or at least the name of the categories.
Can I do it by frequency, density, spectrum, etc?

My goal is to write a code that can classify the instruments, without having to use deep learning, but solely signal processing if that's possible.
I've tried to read about what differentiates piano sounds and guitar sounds for example but I haven't had much luck incorporating it into a code.

How would you suggest me to classify the instruments, and what steps should I follow?

Edit: and if it's not possible for a few instruments mixed together, how can I identify a single instrument using frequency analysis or something similar?

Comment: This seems to me to be an impossible problem.  If one had isolated notes from a single instrument at a time, then a time-frequency-amplitude analysis could possibly do it, but all mixed together, you can't really see what is happening spectrally for a single instrument. I would guess that a deep learning AI approach could work, but I have no idea how feasible that is without vast resources available.

Comment: If I had one instrument at a time, and not a few mixed together, how could I do it?

Comment: @adimath: you have already asked that question.  Stackexchange wants neat, answerable questions with neat, pertinent answers.  It's not a discussion group.

Comment: Reluctantly voting to close as lacking focus.  The _real_ reason is because the question, as posed, cannot be answered.  If I'm not mistaken, **we don't know** -- and by "we" I mean all of humanity.  *If* this can be done with today's technology at all, it will be done using deep learning and CNNs, and no one will quite know what's going on under the hood.  I read paper after paper between 1990 and the early 2000's about rules-based AI approaches to this sort of stuff, and **it didn't work**.

Comment: (Committing a Stackexchange sophism by extending a comment -- sigh).  So, without being cynical, no matter what it sounds like: give up on rules-based AI, make something that shows promise using something trained (statistical inference or deep learning), make a business case that'll get you at least $10M in funding, hire three or four PhD's and a support staff to build a product around their algorithms, and after a year you'll either have a "yes" and you'll be rich, or you'll have a "no" and you'll have a bunch of business contacts.  Or get your own PhD in that field, and grants.

Answer (score 2):

Due to lack of reputation, I am unable to comment and am putting a response as an answer here.

In general, this is an extremely difficult problem because of the wide variety of instruments and their variations. A related problem is identifying what key is pressed on a keyboard using acoustic measurements of the keys, which has been attempted with mixed results [here](https://github.com/ggerganov/kbd-audio). The most robust solution to that problem is essentially creating a [matched filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter) for each of the keys, which is performed by recording each key individually, or using some known training set that does not contain simultaneous key strokes. This solution usually breaks down when trying to detect keys on a different keyboard that is not included in the training data.

To equate it to your problem, it would be like recording every note of every instrument you want to detect and matched filtering against that. The major difference is that in music, multiple instruments may be playing simultaneously and could be playing more than one note at a time (i.e. chords). To overcome this, it might be possible to perform the matched filter in the frequency domain instead using a short-time Fourier transform and allow for common chords in the filter. However, every instrument has it's own unique harmonic response which makes it challenging to generalize your detection to instruments you have not trained on. If you were trying to detect instruments outside of your training data, you would either need a model of how that instrument generates acoustic signals or resort to AI with a unreasonably large amount of training data.

Assuming you are able to get a frequency domain matched filter to work relatively consistently, you will almost certainly have a large amount of false positives. To improve this, you could implement a probabilistic model that only announces a detection if an instrument is present for a given percentage of time over some window.

As others have mentioned, many others have attempted this with limited success and I'm sure others have tried to implement the above approach before. But if you are only trying to detect instruments you have trained on with minimally complex music, you might have some reasonable success. At that point, machine learning might even have a chance.

Comment: I don't think that matched filter approach will work in real life. As the acoustic will have its impact. Better have profiling and finger printing per instrument or just train a net.